# WiFi repeater using ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

I have a [ESP8266](https://alselectro.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/esp1.png) and I wonder if it is possible to create a Wi-Fi signal repeater using this module.

- I can create a network so that devices connect it.
- I can connect to an existing network.

But I can not connect the network created with the network that I connected

Does anyone know how to do this? or you have any examples?

Comment: Even if that is possible, the speed will be very low.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a single ESP8266 be both an access point and a client, at least not using the exposed API (recall that the Arduino libaries do not implement much functionality themselves, all they do is call the underlying RTOS API).

Also, a signal repeater is not a radio-only device. It would have to understand the low-level 802.11* protocols and packet types so you don't end up with forwarding loops. You can't do it just by connecting a pair of 8266s back-to-back over SPI and blindly forward packets; there is a lot of networking code that would have to be written.